# If $L$ is a line bundle on a scheme $X$, what is the ring $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{ \otimes n})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

If $L$ is a line bundle on a scheme $X$, what is the ring $A = \oplus \Gamma(X, L^{ \otimes n})$? This ring comes up in an exercise that I am struggling with right now, and I would like some insight into what this ring ... "is." What is the motivation for considering it? Maybe there is some geometric insight that I am missing? How should I think about it?

And also, if $F$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf, $M = \oplus \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ is an $A$ module. Again, what is the geometric meaning of this construction?

My thoughts: If $X$ is projective space, and $L$ a line bundle of positive degree, then $A$ is some veronese subring of the homogeneous coordinate ring. What is $M$ in that case? How does $\tilde{M}$ relate to the sheaf $F$?

(Sorry, I know this is a poorly posed question. I am just getting really confused with the corresponding exercise 13.3H in Ravi's notes - I don't want to ask for a solution to that though. I think I know how a proof should go, but the objects involved are confusing me.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure this constitutes a complete answer, but at least let me give you some examples and remarks that indicate the importance of this construction (and, hopefully, therefore also a little bit of the geometric intuition behind it).

It's probably useful to play around with it a bit more, beyond the examples I give. What happens for example if $X$ is affine?

**Example.** Let $\mathscr L$ is a torsion line bundle (say on a smooth projective variety $X$), e.g. $\mathscr L^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal O$, but $\mathscr L \not\cong \mathcal O$. Then $\Gamma(X, \mathscr L^{\otimes n})$ is $0$ for all $n$ odd, and $1$-dimensional for $n$ even. This is generated by a nonzero section of $\Gamma(X,\mathscr L^{\otimes 2})$.

**Example.** If $X$ is a projective scheme and $\mathscr L = \mathcal O(1)$ is some very ample line bundle, then
$$A = \bigoplus_{n = 0}^\infty \Gamma(X,\mathscr L^{\otimes n})$$
is the affine coordinate ring of $X$ with respect to the given projective embedding. We know that this ring might depend on the embedding; however, it is always finitely generated (even if $\mathscr L$ is merely ample as opposed to very ample: exercise).

**Erratum.** The above example is not quite correct, as pointed out by Daniele A. The ring $A$ only equals the affine coordinate ring of $X$ with respect to the given embedding if the embedding is projectively normal. In general, they are isomorphic in large enough degree, hence the ring $A$ is still finitely generated (but not necessarily in degree $1$).

**Remark.** On the other hand, one can turn this around and ask if we can use this ring to *define* a projective embedding of $X$, if we have no idea what $X$ is. This is an idea that has proven very useful in the minimal model programme (MMP): if we let $\mathscr L = \omega_{X/k} = \Omega_{X/k}^n$, then we could try to ask whether the natural morphism
$$X \to \operatorname{Proj} \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma(X, \omega_{X/k}^{\otimes n})$$
is an isomorphism, or at least a birational map. The right-hand side is called the *canonical model* of $X$.

**Example.** If $X = \mathbb P^n$, then this is obviously not true. Indeed $\omega_X = \mathcal O(-n-1)$, none of whose tensor powers has any sections. That is, the right hand side is just a point.

There are examples where the right hand side (if finitely generated) can have any dimension between $0$ and $n$ (the dimension of $X$); this is then the *Kodaira dimension* of $X$ (although this is not literally the definition of Kodaira dimension).

**Remark.** On the other hand, it is a celebrated (and very recent!) theorem of [Birkar–Cascini–Hacon–McKernan](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610203) that the canonical ring is finitely generated, whenever $X$ is smooth and projective. This result was [obtained independently by Siu](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610740) using analytic methods in the case where $X$ is of general type. (Don't worry, I don't understand any of the words the two papers use either.)

Reid had already proven (in 1980): if $X$ is smooth, proper, and of general type, under the assumption of finite generation of the canonical ring, the morphism $X \to \operatorname{Proj} \bigoplus \Gamma(X,\omega_{X/k}^{\otimes n})$ is birational.

These two results together more or less solve the minimal model programme for varieties of general type.

**Remark.** Mark has indicated below that there exist examples of line bundles for which the ring $\bigoplus \Gamma(X,\mathscr L^{\otimes n})$ is not finitely generated. A place to read about this example is Lazarsfeld's Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I, Example 2.3A (p.158).

The idea is to construct a divisor $D$ on a surface $X$ such that the base locus of $mD$ always contains the same curve $C$, but $mD - C$ is base-point free. Then the ring $\bigoplus \Gamma(X,\mathcal O(mD))$ cannot be finitely generated, because otherwise the multiplicity of $C$ in the base locus would go to infinity.

Comment: Nice answer, but the bit about $2$-torsion seems off to me: you need a generator in degree $0$, but that's it; it's $0$ in odd degrees, you don't need generators there. So the section right is finitely generated.  You're right of course that finite generation isn't true for every line bundle, but the examples are a little more elaborate.  Note that BCHM proves finite generation of the canonical ring for any smooth variety (including Enriques surfaces, but there it's obvious).  What needs general type is the existence of minimal models.

Comment: Ah, you're right; I mixed up even and odd. In that case I do not know an example of non-finite generation off the top of my head.

Comment: The "usual" example is due to Nagata: you blow up a bunch of points (12?) on an elliptic curve in P^2 that are cleverly chosen with respect to the group law.  It's spelled out in Lazarsfeld's book "Positivity in Algebraic Geometry", but I don't have it on me so I can't tell you the precise reference.

Comment: Do you mean [Hironaka's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka's_example)? It has a line bundle that does not come from a divisor, maybe that's the joke. (I guess the thing you describe sounds different. I have been unable to locate the example in Lazarsfeld. There is a treatment of Hironaka's example, but that doesn't mention finite generation.)

Comment: Oops, I guess the example is actually due to Zariski.  It's in the "Examples and Complements" section of Ch 2 in Lazarsfeld (though I still don't have the exact number).  It's also not hard to get examples from the Cutkosky construction, which I guess are also somewhere in the book.

Comment: Thanks. The precise reference is Lazarsfeld, Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I, Example 2.3 A (p.158). The line bundle is even big and nef, which is supposedly a very slight generalisation of being ample. (I imagine that without the big and nef assumption it might be much easier to construct a counterexample.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. About your first example - part of your claim is that a non-trivial 2-torsion line bundle has no nonzero global sections? I don't understand why that is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If $s$ is a nonzero global section of $\mathscr L$, then $s \otimes s$ is a nonzero global section of $\mathcal O$, hence nowhere vanishing. But then $s$ is nowhere vanishing, giving an isomorphism $s \colon \mathcal O \to \mathscr L$. (In divisor language: if $D$ is effective and nonzero, than $D$ cannot be torsion.)

Comment: Just a remark about the case $\mathscr{L}$ very ample: if $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^r$ is the embedding determined by $\mathscr{L}$ and if by homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$  one means $k[X_0,\dots,X_r]$ modulo the ideal of $X$, then this is not always the same as $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} H^0(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes n})$. For this to be true we need that the embedding is projectively normal, i.e. that all the maps $H^0(\mathbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}(n)) \to H^0(X,\mathscr{L}^n)$ are surjective.

Comment: From this perspective it might also be worth mentioning the work of Cascini-Corti-Lazic. They prove finite generation (well, for a more general section ring) first and deduce everything else.

Comment: @Remy Isn't it possible that $s \otimes s = 0$, in the case of sufficiently nonreduced behavior on the base scheme? For example, on $Spec k[x]/(x^2)$, the nonzero global section of $O_X$ x has $x \otimes x = 0$. This doesn't give a counterexample to your claim, but do you maybe need to assume $X$ is reduced? Also, about the claim for divisors, on the affine quadratic cone $Spec k[x,y,z] / (xy - z^2)$, the divisor $Y$ corresponding to the $y = z = 0$ is effective and nonzero and torsion (Hartshorne 6.5.2). (So maybe you want to require locally factorial, integral, Noetherian, separated?)

Comment: @AreaMan: I was thinking of smooth projective varieties; i.e. the most 'geometric' setting imaginable. But maybe I should have said so explicitly; I agree that there are pathological counterexamples to my statement.

Comment: @Hoot I was unaware of the CCL papers. It does like nice and very related. However, the statement itself is a bit technical, and I personally don't think that it clarifies the point any more than the BCHM result does.

Comment: Shouldn't I be concerned about the commutativity of this ring $\oplus \gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$? Generally, I think $s \otimes t \not = t \otimes s $ in $L^{\otimes 2}$ (though there is a natural isomorphism exchanging them). Maybe what we really want is the global sections of the symmetric product $\Gamma(X, Sym^* L)$? Anyway, I'm confused now.

Comment: Locally the map $\mathscr L \times \mathscr L \to \mathscr L \otimes \mathscr L$ can just be viewed as the multiplication $\mathcal O \times \mathcal O \to \mathcal O$ (using the identification $\mathcal O \otimes \mathcal O \cong \mathcal O$). Commutativity follows from the same property of the usual multiplication.

Comment: @Remy But this identification doesn't glue over the entire scheme...maybe the point you are making is that a choice of this identification shows that the stalks of $s \otimes t$ and $t \otimes s$ are equal at each point of the scheme X, since they become equal in the trivialization?

Comment: Correct: to check two elements agree, one can work locally.