# Does Ample imply direct image algebra finitely generated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme, $f: X \to S$ be a projective morphism and $\mathcal{L}$ an $f$-ample invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Is the $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra $\bigoplus_{m ∈ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} f_*(\mathcal{L}^{\otimes m})$ finitely generated over $\mathcal{O}_S$?

There are many technical conditions in [Stacks Project 01VJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VJ), but none mention finite generation of the algebra above.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610138/if-l-is-a-line-bundle-on-a-scheme-x-what-is-the-ring-oplus-n-geq-0-ga/1610225#1610225 suggests that the answer is yes (at least in favorable settings). I’m a bit surprised not to have found a complete argument on the site, I may write one later. The idea is that (if I’m not mistaken) you can use ampleness to show that for large enough $k$, $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_S, O(k)) \rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes k})$ is onto.

Comment: The argument here can be carried over to this situation as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2046921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer because I’m not satisfied by the arguments in the link (they’re elliptic).

**Edit**: my argument itself was lacking. That’ll teach me to be a critic. It’s corrected now.

Clearly, we can assume that $S$ is affine and the spectrum of the Noetherian ring $A$.

Let $\iota: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_S$ be a closed immersion such that $\iota^{\star}O(1)=\mathcal{L}^{\otimes d}$ for some $d \geq 1$.

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_A} \rightarrow \iota_{\star} \mathcal{O}_X$.

Then, for every $l \geq 1$, we have an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{K}(l) \rightarrow O(l) \rightarrow \iota_{\star} \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl} \rightarrow 0$.

Therefore, for all $l\geq L$ for some $L > 0$, $H^1(\mathbb{P}^n_A, \mathcal{K}(l))=0$, hence $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_A,O(l)) \rightarrow H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl})$ is onto.

Since $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_A, O(1))^{\otimes l} \rightarrow H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_A, O(l))$ is onto, it follows that $\bigoplus_{m \geq 0}{H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes dm})}$ is generated in degree $\leq L$. Since every $f_{\star} \mathcal{L}^{\otimes l}$ is coherent, $G_d:=\bigoplus_{m \geq 0}{H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes dm})}$ is finitely generated over $A$.

Now, let $\mathcal{F}$ be any coherent sheaf on $X$. Then there is an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{A}\rightarrow (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes -ds})^{\oplus r} \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow 0$ for some $s \geq 0$.

Since, for all large enough $l \geq 0$, $H^1(X,\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl})=0$, for all large enough $l \geq 0$, $H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes d(l-s)})^{\oplus r} \rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl})$ is onto.

It follows that $\bigoplus_{l \geq 0}{H^0(X,\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl})}$ is a finitely generated module over $G_d$.

Apply the above with $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{L}^{\otimes k}$ for $0 \leq k < d$: it follows that $G_1$ is a finite $G_d$-algebra, while $G_d$ is finitely generated over $A$, which concludes.

Comment: When you define $\iota$, you have replaced $\mathcal{L}$ with a positive integer multiple so that it is very ample. Why does does the finite generation of $\bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} f_* (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes dm})$ imply the finite generation of $\bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} f_* (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes m})$, where $d$ is a positive integer?

Comment: @SeparatedScheme: thank you for pointing this out! My argument was indeed very incomplete, it should be better now.

Comment: How do you get the short exact sequence with $\mathcal{K}(l)$, $\mathcal{O}(l)$ and $\iota_* \mathcal{L}^{dl}$? Since tensoring is only right-exact, if you tensor the short exact sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{O} \to \iota_* \mathcal{O}_X \to 0$$ with $\mathcal{O}(l)$ over $\mathcal{O}$, then we get an exact sequence $$\mathcal{K}(l) \to \mathcal{O}(l) \to \iota_* \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{\mathcal{O}} \mathcal{O}(l) \to 0.$$ Why is this tensoring also left-exact and why is $\iota_* \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{\mathcal{O}} \mathcal{O}(l)$ equal to $\iota_* \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(l)$ is locally free over $\mathcal{O}$, so $-\otimes_{\mathcal{O}} \mathcal{O}(l)$ is exact. The rest is the *projection formula*: $(f_{\star}\mathcal{F}) \otimes \mathcal{G} \cong f_{\star}(\mathcal{F} \otimes f^{\star}\mathcal{G})$ for a (say) quasi-compact separated morphism of schemes $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, $\mathcal{G}$ flat on $Y$. To prove it, there’s (eg through the $f^{\star},f_{\star}$ adjunction) a canonical map from left to right. Unravelling the definitions on affine open subsets shows it’s an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that part now. I found the projection formula from Proposition 2.32 in Liu - Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, 2002.
$$.$$
How do we get $H^1(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{K}(l)) = 0$?
$$.$$
Also, how do we prove that $\bigoplus_{m \geq 0} H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes d m})$ is generated in degree $\leq L$?

My thoughts: every $m \geq 2L$ can be written as $m = m_1 + \ldots + m_n$, where for all $i$, $L \leq m_i \leq 2L-1$. We have surjections
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{O}(m_i)) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes d m_i}).
$$
Not sure what to do next.

Comment: $H^1(\mathbb{P},\mathcal{K}(l))$ vanishes for $l \geq L$ because $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is ample (I guess you can check Chapter 5 of Qing Liu [and its errata]). Then if $m \geq L$, $H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes dm}$ comes from a section of $H^0(\mathbb{P},\mathcal{O}(m))$, which is generated by sections of $H^0(\mathbb{P},\mathcal{O}(1))$, therefore $H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes dm})$ is generated by sections of $H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes d})$…

Comment: I understand now why $H^1(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{O}(l)) = 0$, thank you. It is Theorem 5.3.2 in Liu.

I'll write some comments (mostly for myself) about $G_d$. We have an $A$-module homomorphism
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{O}(1))^{\otimes l} \to H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes d})^{\otimes l}.
$$
Since sheafification is a functor, we have a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^0(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{O}(1))^{\otimes l} @>>> H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes d})^{\otimes l}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
H^0(\mathbb{P}, \mathcal{O}(l)) @>>> H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes dl}).
\end{CD}

Comment: Where does the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{A} \to (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes -ds})^{\oplus r} \to \mathcal{F} \to 0
$$
come from?

Comment: It’s because $\mathcal{L}$ is ample, see Stacks.

Comment: This is the final point which I do not understand. If you could state a precise reference or a precise statement that you are using, I can accept the answer.

I have found [Lemma 0AG6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AG6), but it gives a surjection from $\bigoplus \mathcal{O}(l_j)$, which is not what we need.

Comment: There is a natural surjection from a finite sum of copies of $\mathcal{O}(l)$ to $\mathcal{O}(l+1)$, so you can get a surjection from $\mathcal{O}(\mu)^{\oplus N}$ where $\mu$ is the minimum of the $l_j$. See also the end of Section 5.1 of Qing Liu (starting with Definition 5.1.33 – be sure to check the errata as well), or Stacks 28.26.13 (7-9).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Since $S$ is quasi-compact, it suffices to prove the case where $S$ is a Noetherian affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is ample. Since $X$ is quasicompact, taking global sections commutes with taking a direct sum, see [Lemma 01AI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01AI). We have
$$
\begin{align}
H^0(S, \bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} f_* (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes m})) & = \bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} H^0(S, f_* (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes m}))\\
& = \bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes m}).
\end{align}
$$
Since $S$ is affine and $\bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} f_* (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes m})$ is quasi-coherent, it suffices to prove that $\bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes m})$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra. This is [Lemma 0B5T(1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B5T).